# How to control a track using a volume slider?

Tags: javascript, slider, continuum

I'm using this volume slider:

```js
// HTML/CSS/JS Volume slider inspired by the Vimeo player

$(document).ready(function () {
    var $input = $('#sliderInput'),
        steps = $input.attr('data-steps');
    defValue = $input.attr('value'),
    $slider = $("<div class='vslider'><div class='vslider_bar'></div><ul class='vslider_sticks'></div>").appendTo($input.parent());
    $input.hide();

    for (var i = 0; i < steps; i++) {
        var $stick = $('<li><div class="vslider_stick"a></div></li>').appendTo($slider.find('.vslider_sticks'));
        $stick.on('mouseenter', function () {
            $(this).addClass('active');
        }).on('mouseleave', function () {
            $(this).removeClass('active');
        });
    }

    var startDrag = function (event) {
        renderUI(getPercent(event));
        $(document.body).on('mousemove', onDrag);
        $(document.body).on('mouseup', stopDrag);
    },
    stopDrag = function (event) {
        $(document.body).off('mouseup', stopDrag);
        $(document.body).off('mousemove', onDrag);
    },
    onDrag = function (event) {
        renderUI(getPercent(event));
    };

    renderUI = function (percent) {
        var index = Math.round(percent * steps);
        index = index < steps ? index : steps;

        $('.vslider_sticks > li').find('div').css('opacity', 0);

        for (var i = 0; i < index; i++) {
            $('.vslider_sticks > li:eq(' + i + ')').find('div').css('opacity', 1);
        }
    };
    renderUI(defValue);

    getPercent = function (event) {
        var percent = (event.pageX - $slider.offset().left) / $('.vslider_sticks').width();
        percent = percent >= 0 ? percent : 0;
        percent = percent <= 1 ? percent : 1;
        return percent;
    };

    $slider.on('mousedown', startDrag);
});
```

```css
body {
    background: #eee;
}
.container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-top: -18px;
    margin-left: -23px;
}
.vslider {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 36px;
}
.vslider * {
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
-webkit-user-select: none;
-khtml-user-select: none;
-moz-user-select: moz-none;
-ms-user-select: none;
user-select: none;
}
.vslider_sticks {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: block;
}
.vslider_sticks > li {
    position: relative;
    text-indent: -99999px;
    width: 5px;
    margin-right: 3px;
    height: 90%;
    top: 10%;
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  
    -webkit-transition: height 60ms ease-out, top 60ms ease-out;
    -moz-transition: height 60ms ease-out, top 60ms ease-out;
    -ms-transition: height 60ms ease-out, top 60ms ease-out;
    -o-transition: height 60ms ease-out, top 60ms ease-out;
    transition: height 60ms ease-out, top 60ms ease-out;
}
.vslider_sticks > li:last-child {
    margin-right: 0;
}
.vslider_sticks > li.active {
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
}
.vslider_stick {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: #d41700;
    opacity: 1;
  
    -webkit-transition: opacity 50ms ease-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 50ms ease-out;
    -o-transition: opacity 50ms ease-out;
    -ms-transition: opacity 50ms ease-out;
    transition: opacity 50ms ease-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <input type="range" value="0.6" data-steps="8" id="sliderInput" />
</div>
```

How do you link it to a track? I'm not sure where to place the variable (or what other editing needs to be done)

Comment: Can you include full `html` and `javascript` at Question?

Comment: You should start accepting answers. You have some questions and ZERO accepted answers. The users here spend time into helping you and, as my grandma always told me, "What you have to say?".

Answer (score 0):

There's no html property to link it to a sound. You have to, programmatically, extract the value on drag and apply it to your sound.

The sound also depends on implementations. The default HTML5 audio element has a `volume` property:

```
var audio = new Audio("AUDIO_SOURCE");
audio.volume = 0.2;
```

Comment: Can't I simply add in this variable into the JS?

var audio = new Audio('src');

Comment: @webdesign123 Yeah, sure. Then you can set `audio.volume` without problem. The thing is that you need to change it when the drag event happens. Going to edit answer to clarify it.